# Unable to render object in JSP Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

Can anyone advise me on how to render the object in JSP.
I have tried so many combinations however it's not printing .
Is my below code correct ?

"result" is an object that I get the values from a class via hibernate.

Here is my code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginvalidate")
public ModelAndView validatelogin (LoginForm request) throws Exception {

    String userName = request.getUserName();
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/loginvalidate"); 
    sessionUser.setUserName(userName);
    System.out.println("username from the controller class " + sessionUser.getUserName());
    List result = loginservice.ValidateLogin(request);
    mav.setViewName("loginvalidate");
    mav.addObject("ToDoList", result);
    return mav;

}
```

Here is my jsp code

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<c:if test="${not empty ToDoList}">
<table>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${ToDoList}">
        <tr>
            <td>${item.id}</td>
            <td>${item.status}</td>
            </tr>
    </c:forEach>
 </table>
</c:if>
```

Here is my sampe JSP using scriptlet , when I try to print the List in system out I'm getting "null".
However I printed the same inside the controller class and it returned some values.

I've tried both session and request to get the attributes.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>
<%@ page import="com.BillingSolution.hibernatebean.BillingSolutionTrx" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>

    <link href="/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>    
<body>


    <% List list = (List) session.getAttribute("ToDoList");
    System.out.println("printing the attributed from List" +list);
        BillingSolutionTrx trx = null;
        for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            trx = (BillingSolutionTrx) iterator.next();
            Long id = (Long) trx.getId();
            String status = (String) trx.getStatus();
            out.println("ID from the to do list JSP " + id);
            out.println("STATUS from the to do list JSP " + status);
        }
            %>



  </body>
 </html>
```

Stack trace

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
at jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._jsp.__loginvalidate._jspService(loginvalidate.jsp:24)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:235)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:567)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:263)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:266)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: Post your jsp code, and exception stack trace

Comment: Hi Sridhar  , I have added my JSP code, Sorry i have no exception, just that it's not printing on the browser .

Comment: I suspect your jstl tag is not working. Can you loop and print the object using scriplets

Comment: May be you get null value in `list` object which gives you a null pointer exception.

Comment: @JavaDev exactly , but when i print this list inside my controller im getting values , Does it mean something wrong while sending my object to the JSP view ?

Comment: @Vinoth you are not setting `list` value in session from controller. use `session.setAttribute("ToDoList",LIST_VALUE)`

Comment: @JavaDev im here using Model and view , If i need to setAttribute inside the session then what is the use of mav.addObject("ToDoList", result);

Comment: @Vinoth than don't use scriptlet. usr EL or JSTL to get list value.

Comment: @javadev Yes I have tried JSTL please find my first jsp page I posted above where It doesn't print anything on my browser that's why I have changed  to scriplet to checker whether any issue on my JSTL tag however same problem for scriplet .

Comment: @Vinoth see my answer below it alternate code you may tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may come from your `<c:if ...>` test. I would write it :

```
<c:if test="${ToDoList.empty == false}">
```

Comment: @Ballesta , no this is not working im having error while use this        Encounter "empty" at line1,column 12.
was expecting :
<IDENTIFIER> ...

Answer (score 0):

You may check this alternate code for your controller function as show below. I have used `ModelMap` class to send your

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginvalidate")
public String validatelogin (LoginForm request,ModelMap map) throws Exception   
{
    String userName = request.getUserName();
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/loginvalidate"); 
    sessionUser.setUserName(userName);
    System.out.println("username from the controller class " + sessionUser.getUserName());
    List result = loginservice.ValidateLogin(request);
    map.addAttribute("ToDoList", result);
    return "loginvalidate"; //Your JSP Page Path
}
```

In your JSP used EL to get value of your list.